# @ProxyCodeSplit how exactly it works?

Tags: gwt, gwtp, code-splitting

I am new to GWT and GWTP. I know what is GWT Code Split and GWTP Proxy Code Split. I've already red:

http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting.html
http://dev.arcbees.com/gwtp/core/presenters/creating-places.html

I assumed that I understand it. So I've like to used.:

I have application with `Administration panel`, where only part of users can access. So there is no need to download `Administration panel` related code for all. So in `Administration Presenter` I've added `@ProxyCodeSplit` like follow:

```
public class AdminAreaPresenter extends Presenter<AdminAreaPresenter.MyView, AdminAreaPresenter.MyProxy> {
    @ProxyCodeSplit
    @NameToken(Routing.Url.admin)
    @UseGatekeeper(IsAdminGatekeeper.class)
    public interface MyProxy extends TabContentProxyPlace<AdminAreaPresenter> {}

    @TabInfo(container = AppPresenter.class)
    static TabData getTabLabel(IsAdminGatekeeper adminGatekeeper) {
        return new MenuEntryGatekeeper(Routing.Label.admin, 1, adminGatekeeper);
    }

    public interface MyView extends View {}

    AppPresenter appPresenter;

    @Inject
    AdminAreaPresenter(EventBus eventBus, MyView view, MyProxy proxy, AppPresenter appPresenter) {
        super(eventBus, view, proxy, AppPresenter.SLOT_TAB_CONTENT);
        this.appPresenter = appPresenter;
    }
}
```

In other Presenters I have `@ProxyStandard` instead of `@ProxyCodeSplit`.

I've run app and log in. then I've opened `Network` tab in chrome's developer console:

[image]

And after opening `Administation Panel` in application:
[image]

As You can see, there is no new resources added to application.

My main app presenter `AppPresenter` implements interfaces `AsyncCallStartHandler, AsyncCallFailHandler, AsyncCallSucceedHandler` from: `com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.proxy`. and I override those methods:

```
@ProxyEvent
@Override
public void onAsyncCallStart(AsyncCallStartEvent event) {
    Window.alert("Async start");
    getView().setTopMessage("Loading...");
}
@ProxyEvent
@Override
public void onAsyncCallFail(AsyncCallFailEvent event) {
    Window.alert("Async fail");
    getView().setTopMessage("Oops, something went wrong...");
}
@ProxyEvent
@Override
public void onAsyncCallSucceed(AsyncCallSucceedEvent event) {
    Window.alert("Async success");
    getView().setTopMessage(null);
}
```

And when I enter `AdmininArea` I am getting to allerts: "Async start", "Async success". So I think that everythink work, but unfortunatelly I don't see any changes in resources. Please help. Am I doing something wrong or what?

Comment: Did you test it in Debug Mode (Super Dev Mode) or using the production compile? AFAIK in Debug Mode code splitting is disabled.

Comment: I've only tested it in super Dev mode. What do You mean by 'is disabled' whole src is downloaded at once. Or download is every time I change place that have code split?- which is happening

Comment: No code split points will be generated and the entire application is donwloaded at once. If you change any code, SDM will re-compile the app and again the entire code will be downloaded. In order to test the code splitting, try to run it in production mode.

Comment: How to run in production mode? I use https://gwt-maven-plugin.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/ And on backend I have spring framework. Currently I run app on tomcat from Eclipse with this plugin https://github.com/gwt-plugins/gwt-eclipse-plugin

Comment: Did you already deploy your app somewhere ? 
Basically you need to compile your GWT app (`mvn gwt:compile`) and then make sure that your `index.jsp` of your backend can load the GWT output.

Comment: I struggle with openshift, but no luck so far. I will try to run tomcat outside the Eclipse IDE, so the plugin won't run SuperDevMode.

Comment: Ok. I've tested and it works, If You could post it as an answer I could accept this and close the post. Thanks

Comment: ok added the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code splitting is disabled in `SuperDevMode` because it is not compatible with the incremental compiler and would also slow down compilation (see this [issue](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues/8559)).

To test code splitting, compile your `GWT` application (`mvn clean install gwt:compile`) and test it in production mode (take war file from target directory and put it in f.e.: Tomcat server catalog: `webapps`).